# What's the name of an eccentric flywheel

Tags: word-request

What's the name of the part that's placed on axis of a motor that has weight off-center, to create vibrations? Say, phone vibration motors have that.

Comment: Do you mean the weight itself, the eccentric rotating mass (ERM)?

Comment: http://www.precisionmicrodrives.com/application-notes-technical-guides/application-bulletins/ab-004-understanding-erm-characteristics-for-vibration-applications

Comment: @snailboat is correct - the part is the eccentric rotating mass or ERM, although sometimes it is referred to as just the "eccentric mass" when the context makes it clear that it's part of a vibration motor.

Comment: @snailboat: Just the technical element with the mass. (without the motor).

Comment: I believe ERM is the answer. Anyone up to posting it for easy +15 points?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you mean the **eccentric rotating mass** (ERM), sometimes called simply the "eccentric mass", as ColleenV notes in her comment.